# Checkmarx Plugin Integration issue with Eclipse and IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkmarx

I have integrated Checkmarx plugin in Eclipse through zip file. But while I am putting server information in Windows ->"CxViewer Preferences" ->Authentication -> Server URL and click on Test button than i am getting "Server is not responding" error. Can somebody help me out to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image: 1]

I was trying it with Eclipse and IntelliJ.

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct? It lacks a port number, and refers to your own machine, while you haven't mentioned installing some kind of server application.

Comment: I think it is customer issue and not technical question

Comment: @Nitind i put like http://localhost:8080/ but it's not worked

Comment: What makes you think a Checkmarx server is running at `http://localhost:8080/`?